# emp logindetails based on conditions in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server. Please tell me how to solve login and logout time calculation in SQL Server based on conditions.

1. If the same empid works multiple shifts, multiple shifts calculation for same date must be time difference is 5 hours then that date consider as multiple shifts for that emp
2. OnFloor time how much time they spent
3. OffFloor time how much time they spent

Sample input data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    [Emp Id] [float] NULL,
    [Area Of Access] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [floor] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-03T03:36:58.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-03-03T03:38:55.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:54:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:54:13.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:54:32.000' AS DateTime), N'Common Area')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-03-05T18:55:01.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (10, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-03-05T19:58:41.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (20, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-02-06T16:03:08.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (20, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-06T22:01:40.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (20, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-02-06T22:42:15.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (20, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T00:33:19.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (20, N'IN', CAST(N'2018-02-07T10:13:11.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([Emp Id], [Area Of Access], [Time], [floor]) VALUES (20, N'OUT', CAST(N'2018-02-07T15:13:10.000' AS DateTime), N'Production Floor')
GO
```

Based on above data I want output like below :

[image]

I tried like below :

```
select
    ShiftDate, ShitStartTime, ShiftEndTime
    , Total_Time = right(concat('0', Total_Time / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', Total_Time % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', Total_Time % 60), 2)
    , OnFloor = right(concat('0', OnFloor / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OnFloor % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OnFloor % 60), 2)
    , OffFloor = right(concat('0', OffFloor / 3600), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OffFloor % 3600 / 60), 2) + ':' + right(concat('0', OffFloor % 60), 2)
    , [Emp ID]
from (
    select
        [Emp ID], ShiftDate = cast(min(Time) as date)
        , ShitStartTime = isnull( min( case when ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='in'
        then 
        Time end  ) ,'1900-01-01')
        , ShiftEndTime = isnull( max( case when ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='out'
        then 
        Time end  ) ,'1900-01-01')
        , Total_Time = sum(ss)
        , OnFloor = sum(iif(ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='in', ss, 0))

        , OffFloor = sum(iif(ltrim(rtrim([Area Of Access]))='out', ss, 0))
from (
        select
            *, ss = datediff(ss, Time, lead(Time) over (partition by [Emp ID], grp order by Time))
        from (
            select
                *, grp = sum(diff) over (partition by [Emp ID] order by Time)
            from (
                select
                    *, diff = iif(datediff(mi, lag(Time) over (partition by [Emp ID] order by Time), Time) > 300

                     and [Area Of Access]='in'
                     , 1, 0)
                from
                    emp
            ) t
        ) t
    ) t
    group by [Emp ID], grp
) t
```

above query is not given expected result .
Please tell me how to  wirte query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Comment: Excellent example of a question: consumable sample data, expected results, and what you've tried, very well done! This was a refreshing change, thank you. :)

Comment: More on topic, I realise there is a language barrier here, however I'm alittle unclear on your statement *multiple shifts calculation for same date must be time difference is 5 hours then that date consider as multiple shifts for that emp*. Are you saying that for a shift on the same day to be considered a different shift the start of the Shift needs to be 5 hours (or more) after the end of the other? if so, what about if someone were to finish at 23;00, and then start again at 01:00? Are these 1 or 2 shifts? They are on separate days, but less than 5 hours apart.